# How do I download an embedded video from a Cdn?

Tags: video, download, cdn

I am trying to download videos from a members portal so that I can watch it in 2x speed. I was looking at the webpage source code and see that the video is from "https://1859811780.rsc.cdn77.org/ftc-introduction/data/video1.mp4" but when I try it I get a 403 error.
Is there a way I can download the video? Thank you!

Comment: Hello, Please share your code what you have tried till now, what code you have gone through, So that People can understand your problem properly where you are stuck at. Find more information about how to ask a good question here stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide the URL of the page that has this video embedded.

Comment: Hi all, thank u for the replies. The website with the embedded video is inside a members portal with a secure login. I did not write any code. I was just wondering if there's any solution from this tech community.